# Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIView', superclass of 'JYGraphPoint'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikit, watchkit

> ```
> #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
>
> @interface JYGraphPoint : UIView {
>     UIColor *strokeColour;
>     UIColor *fillColour;
> }
>
> @property UIColor * strokeColour;
> @property UIColor *fillColour;
>
> @end
> ```

Error below show after i set Target Membership to a watchkit extension.

/......./JYGraphPoint.h:11:27: Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIView', superclass of 'JYGraphPoint'

Please help. thanks.

Comment: i suggest you to delete JYGraphPoint.h and JYGraphPoint.m and paste the code intelligentely!

Comment: @Simon have you done mapping class with the UIVIew in storyboard/Xib?

Comment: watch kit doesn't support UIView

Comment: im using this code: https://github.com/johnyorke/JYGraphView
his example no error, but mine got. i try use podfile or copy files to my project, both ways not working. i have no idea why his example works perfect on watchos but not mine.